# Bash/perl Printing line(s) from file until a character with conditions

Tags: perl, bash, parsing

I'm trying to scan a file for lines containing a specific string, and print the lines to another file.

However, I need to print out multiple lines until ")" character IF the line containing the string ended in "," ignoring whitespaces.

Currently I'm using

```
for func in $fnnames
do
  sed/"$func"/p <$file >>$CODEBASEDIR/function_signature -n
done
```

where $func contains the string I look for, but of course it doesn't work for the restriction.

Is there a way to do this?  Currently using bash, but perl is fine also.
Thanks.

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is tricky because your restrictions are not precise. You say - I think - that a block should look like this:

```
foo,
bar,
baz)
```

Where `foo` is the string that starts the block, and closing parenthesis ends it. However, you could also be saying:

```
foo bar baz) xxxxxxxxxxx,
```

And you only want to print until the `)`, which is to say `foo bar baz)`, IF the line ends with comma.

You could **also** be saying that only lines that end with a comma should be continued:

```
foo,   # print + is continued
bar    # print + is not continued
xxxxx  # ignored line
foo    # print + is not continued
foo,
bar,
baz)   # closing parens also end block
```

Since I can only guess that you mean the first alternative, I give you two options:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub flip {
    while (<DATA>) {
        print if /^foo/ .. /\)\s*$/;
    }
}

sub ifchain {
    my ($foo, $print);
    while (<DATA>) {
        if (/^foo/) {
            $foo = 1;          # start block
            print;
        } elsif ($foo) {
            if (/,\s*$/) {
                print;
            } elsif (/\)\s*$/) {
                $foo = 0;      # end block
                print;
            }
            # for catching input errors:
            else { chomp; warn "Mismatched line '$_'" }
        }
    }
}


__DATA__
foo1,
bar, 
baz)
sadsdasdasdasd,
asda
adaffssd
foo2,   
two,    
three)
yada
```

The first one will print any lines found between a line starting with `foo` and a line ending with `)`. It will ignore the "lines end with comma" restriction. On the positive side, it can be simplified to a one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^foo/ .. /\)\s*$/' file.txt
```

The second one is just a simplistic if-structure that will consider both restrictions, and warn (print to STDERR) if it finds a line inside a block that does not match both.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if 1 .. /\).*,\s*$/'
```